# while installing guile-1.8-dev on ubuntu

Tags: error-handling

$ sudo apt-get install guile-1.8-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package guile-1.8-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'guile-1.8-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'guile-1.8-dev'

Comment: What is your question? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Two things: 1. Either you have not configured the repo required for the package, or 2. You are misspelling the package name.  I suggest you search the web on information pertaining to the package first.

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and find the exact name of the package you are looking for: `apt-cache search guile`. It will give you a whole list of packages with 'guile' in it, and you need to find which one you are looking for.

Then do `sudo apt-get install [found package name here]` to install that package.

1.8-dev is available in Ubuntu 16.04 repo's, but not in 18.04. You can also look up packages at [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com).